# What file system are memory cards formatted with?

Tags: memory-card, storage

Is there an industry standard file system cards are formatted with (when you first get them, and/or after a camera formats them)? FAT32, FAT16?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They're formatted with FAT16 or FAT32 (FAT32 is required for card sizes >2GB), and have a fairly specific (though simple) directory structure something like this:

```
ROOT --- DCIM -+- ###ABCDE
               |
               +- ###ABCDE
               |
               ...
```

`###` is from 100-999, and need not be consecutive. ABCDE is free text.

This structure won't be recreated if you format on a computer, but an in-camera format will usually construct it (or it will be built as required on a blank card).

There are similar standards for file names, and it's all specced out in detail by the [Design Rule for Camera File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system), which you can read in full here (PDF):
http://www.jeita.or.jp/cgi-bin/standard_e/pdfpage.cgi?jk_n=51

Answer (score 6):

Such cards are usually formatted as FAT32 or exFAT, as that is nearly a universally compatible format at this point. It might depend on what kind of memory card you are referring to...SDHC, CF?

Comment: could be me, but I've seen FAT16 or exFAT use much more than FAT32. (when formated by the camera)

Comment: exFAT is really just an extension to the baser FAT32 that increases disk size, removes limitations, etc. It uses larger numbers to reference sectors, file sizes, etc. I guess its important to make the distinction. I've never seen FAT16, as it would only be useful for extremely small card sizes of 1Gb or less.

Comment: FAT16 had fewer patent issues so it was preferred for the smaller cards.

Comment: Gocha. I don't think I've ever used a card smaller than 4Gb, and most of mine are 8 or 16gb.

Comment: I've still got a 32 Megabyte CompactFlash card from an old digicam, still works on my latest DSLR but only holds 3 photos :-O

Answer (score 5):

The SD standard formally requires

- FAT16 for regular SD cards
- FAT32 for SDHC
- FAT64 ("exFAT") for SDXC

those formats are indeed to be used by the in-camera format function.

The latter choice has long been under fire by open source activist both due to strict licensing of the exFAT specifications - thus its poor support on anything that's not a recent Windows, Mac OS X or embedded system - and due to it being an allegedly **less safe system** (saving only one copy of the directory index) although this weakness is less critical on a write/read/reformat workflow as suggested by most camera manufacturers, and followed by pros and amateurs who don't keep their photos for future in-camera playback.

Comment: Since August 2019, exFAT has been released as an open standard.

Answer (score 0):

Use FAT32 if you can, since FAT16 is becoming rare and fewer computers support this mode

Comment: Really? FAT16 is still supported by Linux and Windows 7, and is still used on lots of embedded devices, I don't think it's going anywhere soon!

Comment: Quick update: In 2020, FAT16 is still supported by all OSes.